# Direct2D - take screenshot

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, direct2d

I am using C++/Direct2D in my windows application, where I am drawing some lines and ellipses between `pRenderTarget->BeginDraw()` and `pRenderTarget->EndDraw()`. I am not using any offscreen bitmap for the drawing as of now, although I am considering it for the future use.

How do I take a screenshot save it as an image (PNG/JPEG or BMP)?

PS: With GDI+, I used **CLSID** and for saving `m_pBmp->Save(strFileName, &pngClsid, NULL);`

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768180/direct2d-how-to-save-content-of-id2d1rendertarget-to-an-image-file/

Comment: @vt. do you happen to have sample codes for implementing as in the above mentioned post?

Answer (score 0):

While debugging a DirectX problem, I wrote some code to save the screen image to a bitmap for later review.  However, it's written for Direct3D and is somewhat old, but, it may provide some insight for you.  You can find it [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/debug/logging/article.php/c6345/Generating-Debug-Bitmaps-for-DirectX.htm).  I would suggest you read the code and see if you can adapt it for your needs.

Comment: well, as you mentioned the problem is, the important functions (or methods) are offered only by D3D, which in my case (D2D) is not relevant.

Comment: could you comment/answer in the context of Direct2D, as the links you provided does not apply in my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not versed in D2D.  My hope was that you could obtain some insight into how I did it with D3D and apply it to your situation.